# React Native MapView not showing on iOS standalone build

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps, expo

I am using `MapView` from [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps). I've gone ahead and built standalone apps for both iOS and Android.

I've followed Expo's [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/) regarding `MapView` with standalone apps.

After building the project, the standalone Android version works perfectly fine but iOS only slightly works. As you can see in the picture the `Marker` shows but not the underlying map. Any ideas why?

**iOS Image:**

[image]

**MapView Code:**

```
<MapView
  style={styles.map}
  customMapStyle={mapStyle}
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  initialRegion={region}
  showsMyLocationButton={false}
  followsUserLocation={true}
  showsUserLocation
  radius={Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.08}
  minZoomLevel={3}
  maxZoomLevel={20}
  rotateEnabled={false}
  pitchEnabled={false}
  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
>
  {locations &&
    locations
      .filter((location) => location.data.status === "live")
      .map((location, index) => {
        return (
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location.data.lat,
              longitude: location.data.long,
            }}
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate("LocationScreen", { location })
            }
            key={index}
          >
            <View style={styles.markerContainer}>
              <Text
                style={styles.text}
                numberOfLines={1}
                adjustsFontSizeToFit
              >
                {location.data.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly mistake! I had the correct API Key for `android.config.googleMaps.apiKey`, but incorrect key for `ios.config.googleMapsApiKey` in my `app.json` file.

Always check twice!

Comment: The other thing to check (which stumped me) is that you've enabled iOS Maps SDK... https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-ios-backend.googleapis.com